# How to extract two part-numerical values from a line in shell script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have multiple text files in this format. I would like to extract lines matching this pattern "pass filters and QC".

File1:

```
Before main variant filters, 309 founders and 0 nonfounders present.
0 variants removed due to missing genotype data (--geno).
9302015 variants removed due to minor allele threshold(s)
(--maf/--max-maf/--mac/--max-mac).
7758518 variants and 309 people pass filters and QC.
Calculating allele frequencies... done.
```

I was able to grep the line, but when I tried to assign to line variable it just doesn't work.

```
grep  'people pass filters and QC' File1
line="$(echo grep 'people pass filters and QC' File1)"
```

I am new to shell script and would appreciate if you could help me do this.

I want to create a tab separated file with just

```
"File1" "7758518 variants" "309 people"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GNU awk

```sh
gawk '
  BEGIN { patt = "([[:digit:]]+ variants) .* ([[:digit:]]+ people) pass filters and QC" }
  match($0, patt, m) {printf "\"%s\" \"%s\" \"%s\"\n", FILENAME, m[1], m[2]}
' File1
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, just remove `double quotes` and `echo` from your command:

```
line=$(grep 'people pass filters and QC' File1)
```

Now view the value stored in variable:

```
echo $line
```

And if your file structure is same, i.e., it will always be in this form: 7758518 variants and 309 people pass filters and QC, you can use awk to get selected columns from output. So complete command would be like below:

```
OIFS=$IFS;IFS=$'\n';for i in $line;do echo $i;echo '';done | awk -F "[: ]" '{print $1"\t"$2" "$3"\t"$5" "$6}';IFS=$OIFS
```

Explanation:

- `IFS` means internal field separator, and we are setting it to `newline` character, because we need to use it in `for` loop.
- But before that, we are taking it's backup in another variable `OIFS`, so we can restore it later.
- We are using a `for` loop to iterate through all the matched strings, and using awk to select, 1st, 2nd, 3rd , 4th and 5th column as per your requirement.

But please note, if your file structure varies, we may need to use a different technique to extract "7758518 variants" and "309 people" part.